# Using INSERT WHERE with variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make an SQL query that :

- IF the $post_id exists then it updates the records,
- IF NOT then then it creates the record

Here is my code

```
$vote_new_total = $vote_total + $vote;
$vote_count = $vote_count + 1;

$query = "  INSERT INTO cute_review_vote (vote_total, vote_count) 
                VALUES ('$vote_new_total', '$vote_count') 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote_total = $vote_new_total, vote_count = $vote_count 
                WHERE post_id = $post_id";
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE post_id = 214748364' at line 4 in in C:\xampp\htdocs\xbm-vote\do_vote.php on line 68

Is this an issue with my syntax or am I missing something more obvious than that?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `where` with `ON DUPLICATE` statement. Always check syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Also, that is not a secure query. Turn that into a prepared statement.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

EDIT: Updating answer since OP didn't understand usage of `ON DUPLICATE` statement:

`ON DUPLICATE` will consider that you're trying to insert a `KEY` value.
Consider the example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `datecreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
);
```

And the query:

`INSERT INTO user (email, name, is_active) VALUES ("user@user.com", "User", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = "User Edited", is_active = 0`

Since we're setting `PRIMARY KEY` as `email`, and the insert statement is inserting a key, then, at the second time you run the query, `ON DUPLICATE` would run once a `email` is already on the table, because it is the `KEY` and you are trying to insert it again, but you defined a `ON DUPLICATE KEY ...`.

If a table runs with a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, is most likely you have to `SELECT post_id` applying some filter with `WHERE` statement.

Comment: how would i go about achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE` wont work well if you have only a `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Consider to use another field as KEY as well, or change the structure of database to another KEY. `ON DUPLICATE` will consider that you are inserting a key, so it can identify its existence, then either update or complete the insert process. Maybe you could provide more details about how is your table, so we can consider alternatives about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my problem.

```
INSERT INTO cute_review_vote (post_id, vote_total, vote_count) 
                VALUES ('$post_id', '$vote_new_total', '$vote_count') 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote_total = $vote_new_total, vote_count = $vote_count
```

I realized, thanks to Fabiano, that the WHERE clause is not required.

```
WHERE post_id = $post_id"
```

Is simply replaced by defining the database entry within the INSERT INTO command.